# Binary String into Decimal Value, formula?

Tags: math, binary, wolfram-mathematica

Using Mathematica

```
Binary String: "FBCD"

#1
I: ImportString["FBCD", {"Binary", "Bit"}]
O: {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, \
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}

#2
I: ImportString["FBCD", {"Binary", "UnsignedInteger32"}]
O: {1145258566}

#3
I: ImportString["FBCD", {"Binary", "Byte"}]
O: {70, 66, 67, 68}
```

What is actual math formula using the byte values {70, 66, 67, 68} in the output of #3 to get the int32 value {1145258566} in the output of #2?

`(70^4)+(66^3)+(67^2)+68` 
I know this isn't correct, looking for the correct formula if there is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

( ( ( 68 * 256 ) + 67 ) * 256 + 66 ) * 256 + 70  = 1145258566

Answer (score 4):

It is

```
FromDigits[Reverse[{70, 66, 67, 68}], 256]
```

That is, `68*256^3 + 67*256^2 + 66*256 + 70`.

Looking at the incorrect formula you mentioned, I suggest reading a bit about [place-value notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation).  Also think about how if you have a kind of variable that can store `k` different values (one byte can store 256 different values, commonly identified with integers through `0..255`), then 2 of these variables can store `k*k = k^2` different values, more generally, `n` of them can store `k^n` different values in total.